# Python: Find string in line based on lookup

Tags: python, dynamic, if-statement, find

is it possible to find a value in a string, where the value is one of any field values in a CSV. E.G...

```
values.csv:

field1,field2,field3
1,abc,123
2,def,456
3,ghi,789
4,jkl,012,
..,..,..
```

So using the fields in the CSV (which won't be very large), can I find whether the line (already defined) contains any of those values (i.e. 'abc|def|ghi|jkl'), so the following results would be expected:

```
'This string is abc' = TRUE
'This is a string' = FALSE
'This def is good' = TRUE
```

etc.

So here I would just be looking for an if statement that uses a dynamic value, so I can fit it in to my code... I currently print out `line` just as proofing stage, so I already have this.

UPDATE:

@korylprince's answer helped here, changed the function slightly to the following:

```
def checkString(text):
    for search in searches:
        #print search <--- TESTING
        if search not in text:
            #print "FALSE" <--- TESTING
            test="FALSE"
        else:
            #print "TRUE" <--- TESTING
            test="TRUE"
            break
     #print test <--- TESTING
     ....
```

Cheers,

Comment: What about "This line is definitely ambiguous"?  Does that contain a "def" or not?

Comment: ideally no, it would be just as an independant string, so I could add something like `strip()` couldn't I?

Comment: Did you mean "line.split()"? Yes, it will work.

Comment: @kalgasnik: modulo punctuation, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand exactly what you want.

From what you said, I think you mean that you have a csv file, values.csv.

From this csv file you want to take all the values in the second column and put them in a list.

Then for any string you give, you want to see if one of those values is in the string.

Try this:

```
# open file and parse values
with open('values.csv') as f:                                               
    searches = [x.split(',')[1] for x in f.read().splitlines()]

# function to check string
def checkString(text):
    # iterate over searches and check each one
    for search in searches:
        if search in text:
            return True
    return False
```

There would be more efficient ways to do this, but if you only have a few records and strings (several hundred or even thousand) this should be fine.

Comment: My script reads (if a control file does not exist) and then tails a rolling log file, it will then read each line, I want to edit this line based a UID (which will be in values.csv for example), so I add a new UID that will apply to mulitple sources, it's a required step of pre-processing (before an application uses it) that is required for my project... if that makes sense

Comment: I understand the string will actually be log file lines. Now you say you want to edit the line. Does that mean actually change it? In the log file? You didn't mention that in the original question, also this will be difficult with a rolling log file.

Comment: sorry, no... edited output will be to a new file... just reading the old file.

Comment: p.s. you'd think being British and having English as my first language, I'd have a strong handle of it... pah!!!

Comment: Okay good. Now will values.csv be changing? Will you be editing it?

Comment: yes it will be appended to or modified, but not on a regular basis, once I have a way for handling most possibilities of logs entries, it will be only when a "new" one appears.

Comment: Okay, so if you used my script, what else would you need? I'm not exactly sure what you want concerning the UID.

Comment: I modified the function a little (I've updated this in my original question). Thanks for the help.

p.s. I wasn't asking about the UID for this part of the solution, I can do that... it was the looping of the csv file that I was struggling with.

THANKS for the help

Answer (score 3):

```
# Your parsed csv file
csv = ['abc', '123', '2', 'def', '456', '3', 'ghi', '789', '4', 'jkl', '012']
lines = ['This string is abc', 'This is a string', 'This def is good']

for line in lines:
    print line, ':', any(word in line for word in csv)
```

Output:

```
This string is abc : True
This is a string : False
This def is good : True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation this time using `DictReader` from the `csv` module:

```
import csv

lines = ['This string is abc', 'This is a string', 'This def is good']

with open(r'C:\Users\BioGeek\Desktop\values.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        word = row[reader.fieldnames[1]] # only take words from the second column
        for line in lines:
            print "Is '{0}' in '{1}': {2}".format(word, line, word in line)
```

Which produces the output:

```
Is 'abc' in 'This string is abc': True
Is 'abc' in 'This is a string': False
Is 'abc' in 'This def is good': False
Is 'def' in 'This string is abc': False
Is 'def' in 'This is a string': False
Is 'def' in 'This def is good': True
Is 'ghi' in 'This string is abc': False
Is 'ghi' in 'This is a string': False
Is 'ghi' in 'This def is good': False
Is 'jkl' in 'This string is abc': False
Is 'jkl' in 'This is a string': False
Is 'jkl' in 'This def is good': False
```